# How to collect logs with syslog-ng from www servers in dmz and send them to server behind firewall(NAT). Can Zabbix proxy solve this?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, dmz, syslog-ng

I have several www servers in DMZ. My monitoring and log gathering server lays in my LAN. There is no comunication like
`WWW server in DMZ ----> monitor server in LAN`.

I can connect DMZ from my LAN

`LAN --via proxy--> WWW server in DMZ`.

I'm going to use syslog-ng. Problem is that syslog-ng work in client-server architecture and clients connect to server to send logs.

Is there a way to configure syslog-ng in some type passive mode that server (in my LAN) will connect to clients(DMZ) and collect logs?

EDIT:
I was reading about Zabbix proxy (zabbix can monitor logs) ... And teoreticaly relying on zabbix docs it will be posible to make my scenario work. Anybody can confirm that?

Comment: Is there any other host in the DMZ that can connect to monitor server?

Comment: no there isn't, LAN is not accessible from outside

Answer (score 2):

What about tunneling, i.e. using [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org)? For every DMZ server to be monitored:

1. Let the logserver start a tunnel to the DMZ server
2. Configure the DMZ server's syslog so that it connects to the tunnel and use it as additional destination

Note: this may work through firewall/NAT (as per your title) but not through proxy (as per your question content).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about syslog-ng, but I know that Splunk can be configured to collect and index log files from client systems periodically. Otherwise, the best I think you would be able to do is to setup a cron job on your log server to rsync the files to something like `/var/log/clientN/*.log`, and manually call logrotate on the client.

Comment: im looking for ready-made solution, i want avoid making logging system from scratch (rsync, email etc..)

Answer (score 1):

This *might* not help, but I'll share how we get around this. Essentially we use multiple DMZs.

- DMZ1 contains Internet-facing hosts and cannot talk back to the inside LAN.
- DMZ2 is a segregated area (on the same firewall, different VLAN) that can talk to hosts in DMZ1 (both ways) but **not** the Internet. Some hosts in DMZ2 can also talk to certain hosts on the inside LAN.

Therefore hosts in DMZ1 that need to syslog centrally/scp files/send email reports do so via a management host in DMZ2. The information on the management host can then be picked up by a host on the inside.